# Angular + Spring on same port

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc

I deploy my angular project and add to resources/static in spring project, next I create simple controller:

```
@Controller
class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
fun index(): String {
    return "index"
}
```

}

And now when I run tomcat and set url to localhost:8080/ everything work well I can click on buttons and browser redirect to proper site, But now if I refresh site or set diffrent url, my angular app stop working and I get 404 or spring endpoints. Question is, how I can set angular as default to load when I type diffrent url than this from controller

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml. Use a filter to foward to index.html for all GET requests to angular URLs.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699687/my-angular-spring-application-routing-does-not-work-when-deployed-on-tomcat/55348102#55348102

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your API endpoints context. For example /api/**. And then, define an endpoint with a regex, something like this ^/api (all other than /api) to resource path.