# My Angular + Spring Application routing does not work when deployed on TomCat

Tags: java, spring, angular, typescript

I am very much new to angular and spring. I might have made some silly mistakes.
I have Angular + Spring app which displays login screen and after that it shows menu.
This works perfectly when not deployed (i.e. when Angular & Spring are running parallel)
But when I deploy the app on tomcat, it does not show login form. 
I followed below steps for deployment -

1. ng build --base-href=./
2. copy all files from angular dist folder to spring static folder
3. create .war file in spring and deploy it in tomcat

my pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.techence</groupId>
        <artifactId>new</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <name>LoginDemoBackend</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>

                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <type>maven-plugin</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    </project>
```

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginFormComponent } from './login-form/login-form.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginServiceService } from './login-service.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MenubarComponent } from './menubar/menubar.component';
import { BranchCreationComponent } from './menubar/branch-creation/branch-
creation.component';
import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LedgerCreationComponent } from './menubar/ledger-creation/ledger-creation.component';

import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './forgot-password/forgot-
password.component';

const routes: Routes = [    
    { path: '', component : LoginFormComponent}, 

    { path: 'menubar', component: MenubarComponent }, 

    { path: 'branchCreation', component: BranchCreationComponent },

    { path: 'ledgerCreation', component: LedgerCreationComponent } 
];

@NgModule({
declarations: [

    AppComponent,

    LoginFormComponent,

    MenubarComponent,

    BranchCreationComponent,

    LedgerCreationComponent,

    ForgotPasswordComponent

  ],
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,

FormsModule,

HttpModule,

HttpClientModule,

RouterModule.forRoot(routes),

  ],


  providers: [
              LoginServiceService,
             { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
            ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Try to add `/index.html` after you tomcat server address.

Comment: doesn't work. it gives error - This localhost page can’t be found

Comment: try setting `server.servlet.context-path=/yourapp` in your Spring Boot `application.properties` file. afterwards try to access your app via `http://localhost:<port>/yourapp`. given an index.html file in your project's webapp directory you should be able to access that page. if you deploy your spring boot app to an external tomcat webcontainer (not embedded!), it will be served under a specific contextpath because a single tomcat instance can host multiple apps served under the same port. with the Spring Boot property `server.servlet.context-path` you can explicitly configure this contextpath.

Comment: I tried the application.properties setting but same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this in your Spring Boot code:

```
@Bean
public ErrorViewResolver customErrorViewResolver() {
    final ModelAndView redirectToIndexHtml = new ModelAndView("forward:/index.html", Collections.emptyMap(), HttpStatus.OK);
    return (request, status, model) -> status == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND ? redirectToIndexHtml : null;
}
```

It works for me and even Angular routing is working. I found it [here](https://github.com/glipecki/spring-with-angular-cli-demo/blob/master/demo-app/src/main/java/net/lipecki/demo/DemoApplication.java).

Comment: this works with tomcat 10 and angular 9. I would like to hear some explanation if possible. So that I could understand the reason behind this

Comment: @rahal-kanishka When you are requesting for your spring app resource (in this case path in your angular app) and spring doesn't have registered mapping or static file for that url it will return 404 error. `ErrorViewResolver` is for determine what should be returned to you in case of error (by default `Whitelabel Error Page` with some message). Solution is based on that if spring can't find something maybe it is placed in your angular app.